# Online turbo / spinning resources

Tags: training, turbo-trainer

Where can I find free online spinning or turbo classes? Ideally videos, but just audio or even an annotated playlist would do.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for StackExchage Q&A format, and can result in a long list of equally applicable answers. Have voted to close.

Comment: If we do end up with such a list, would that be such a bad thing? I'd say the world was better with it than without.

Comment: Yes, it would be bad. The mission of Stack Exchange is to make the internet better with independent, reliable content. Such a list is going to be outdated quickly, particularly lonks to videos. A page of dead links doesn't help anyone. 

Better than asking for links would be if you asked what to look for, or how to identify a good resource. You'd almost certainly get example links, but they wouldn't be the point of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [The Sufferfest](http://www.thesufferfest.com/).  I haven't tried these out yet as I need to get up the courage to try out my new rollers.

Comment: Not seen those before - look pretty good actually. $12 a video isn't that bad actually ... might give it a go myself

Comment: I have four sufferfest videos as well as a few spinervals (around $25-$30 DVDs) and am preferring the sufferfest videos lately. 

You download a large mp4 video file when you purchase a sufferfest. If you have a laptop or computer to ride in front of thats great. 

I had to create an iDVD project on my Mac and burn to a DVD to play out in the garage where my trainer/bike/tv/dvd play lives.

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of plans on [turbotraining.co.uk](http://www.turbotraining.co.uk/). They're text only, but if you subscribe you can use the online "player" which works really well. The audio is either supplied by digitally imported radio (trance channel) or you could just have your own music.

As an alternative, I met the guys from [powerblast](http://audiofuel.co.uk/turbo-training-music/powerblast-turbo-training-music) at the TCR show last year. They've created audio sets that have variable BPMs with the idea that you match your RPM to the music. I've not tried them myself but they seem like a pretty good idea.

Personally, I find that so long as you have a specific and varied set, and some decent music in the background, it's not too tortuous. If you try to do an hour with no set in mind then it becomes tedious as hell!

Comment: Like the turbotraining site - it seems to me if they could synchronise a playlist to the activity it would be perfect. Powerblast very nice, I just wish a little cheaper.

Comment: re powerblast ... that's why I've not tried them myself!

Comment: I do see that they offer a free sample http://audiofuel.co.uk/free-running-music

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of fitness and workout music collections available on iTunes, with some offering more than a 100 pieces of music for less than $10US. The concept is you put together your own program using available music. You can also put together your own training program using available commercial music for your own use. Pick songs that have a good solid beat. For an hour program choose an introductory piece of music or pieces that give a fast paced beat that can be used with a bike on a training stand or rollers with gears set for low resistance like you were on a flat road. Increase the resistance and vary the music to match your theoretical ride -- flats, hills up, hills down, etc. We have Spinning classes in the United States and they are available in other countries as well. I recommend you contact a Spinning studio or a fitness center that has Spinning classes and take some to see what can be done and how the music is integrated in a visualized ride. A good reputable Spinning class will have you warm up at the beginning of the class and cool down at the end with appropriate controlled stretching included. Spinning classes use stationary bikes designed for Spinning classes but it is possible to set a road bike up on rollers or stand to mimic the feel. To make my bike more stable I have a training stand on the back wheel and I took a training stand that was no longer functional (I wore it out) and modified it to fit the front wheel to provide a very stable platform that allows me to not just sit and ride but also to stand out of the saddle for a more complete training session.